# Change editor contents of ckeditor4

Tags: jquery, html, css, ckeditor4.x

My requirement is to change the styling of editor contents part inside

**HTML**

```
<div id="cke_1_contents" class="cke_contents cke_reset">
    <iframe src(unknown) ...> .. </iframe>
</div>
```

Inside div, there is an iframe inside editor div which makes me unable to change styling DOM elements inside iframe using css.

I tried to change with the help of jQuery, but not able to do. So I created new page named **editor.html** where I copied everything provided inside  `<iframe> ..... </iframe>` and with the help of jquery, I changed **src** attribute of **iframe**.

Now, I faced a problem when I clicked on any button on toolbar of ckeditor4, then it gives javascript error "***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined***". 
Please tell me how can I customize inside content of `<div id="cke_1_contents"` and target this area by toolbar buttons?

I am adding further information. Please have a look at following image:
[image]

I copied everything from this code selected in red rectangle, and written in editor.html page and using following jquery, I replaced with my own. I have written following jQuery:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function() { 
            htmlEditor = '<span id="cke_52" class="cke_voice_label">Press ALT 0 for help</span>';
            htmlEditor += '<iframe src="editor.html" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, editor1" aria-describedby="cke_52" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>';
            $('#cke_1_contents').html(htmlEditor);
```

});

And I can change css of editor part, not toolbar, only editor part in **editor.html** page. But with this, I faced a problem, whenever I clicked on any button on toolbar like insert image, bold italics etc, it does not target to editor replaced with my own htmlEditor with the help of jquery, it gives error "***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined***".

Now, I need,
(i) Either I should able to change css of editor part of ckeditor4
(ii) Or If I changed the editor with my own html with exact copy of all divs and classes except url in iframe as I done above, I should able to target toolbar buttons to my own created editor.

Comment: Please Refer https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1.html

Comment: Documentation I also can read and viewed but did not find answer. If you can link to specific page where it is mentioned that "target toolbar buttons to your own created editor", that will really help me.

Comment: plugin is for that purpose. Please share a runnable code.

Comment: @SumeshTG: I have added more information, if you can give me direction, it will be really helpful for me.

Comment: Please explain what task are you trying to do with ckeditor. Couldn't replace the structure of ckeditor it depends on there library files. We can do the customization,add extra features on there tool bar ..etc

Comment: @SumeshTG: Yes, API documentation of CKeditor provides information about customization, extra features of toolbar only, nothing about editor part. I need certain requirements like make the editor part similar to microsoft word or google sheet. I want to divide div into pages. It can be possible with css or jquery, but there is no documentation related to customization of editor part, there is customization or styling of toolbar only. I also need certain css change in editor part.

Comment: Please include prototype of desired output. See there is doc editor too https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/#document

Comment: This is the working prototype and here editor is provided by ckeditor https://jsfiddle.net/x1fc9saq/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see below for accessing iframe document, demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vt1far8g/)

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
<script>
  var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
  editor.setData('Hello world!');

  CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(event) {
    var iframe = document.querySelector('#cke_1_contents iframe');
    var cke_doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    cke_doc.body.style = `background-color: yellow;
            font-size: 28px;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px #b4bd21;`
  });
</script>
```

Comment: this is not answer to my question. Your answer changing the text inside the editor. I asked, I changed the html part inside div. If I changed html content using jquery, then toolbar buttons do not target to that my own newly created editor.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ewwink, working perfectly fine. I am able to do css changes whatever I need.